# Set Visual Studio to open XAML editor for files with other extension (.txaml)

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, editor

I'm trying to set up Visual Studio 2019 to open files with special extension (.txaml) with basic XAML editor.

I have found Options > Text Editor > File Extension setting that could possibly be helpful.

But there is no XAML editor in the list of available editors.

Is there any way to add XAML editor to that list?

Or is there any other place in Options where editor to file extension dependency could be set up?

Of course I have no problems with opening .xaml files in XAML editor

---

UPDATE

I have found out that what I call XAML editor is actually Automatic Editor Selector(XML). And my current situation is that if I open standard `.xaml` file with Automatic Editor Selector(XML) it opens as standard XAML editor, but if I open my `.txaml` file the same way with Automatic Editor Selector(XML) it opens somehow differently as simple XML editor.

By the way, in my `.txaml` files there is usual xaml code

Is it possible to make Automatic Editor Selector(XML) act the same way for `.txaml` files as it does for `.xaml` files?

Comment: By XAML editor do you mean the XAML designer that renders the UI and lets you click on controls, etc.?

Comment: @ClicheCoffeeMug actually I have no interest in UI designer, I use only text editor for XAML files, but of course they come together

Comment: Ahh, I'm afraid I may have misunderstood your question then. I just created a .txaml file in VS manually and it opens just fine, but I'm assuming you'd like to set VS to be the default application for opening .txaml files? Or is that incorrect?

Comment: @ClicheCoffeeMug maybe my explaination wasn't very clear, right now I have no problem with opening my .txaml files in vs, the problem is that the editor in which they open is a standart xml editor, it is very simple and don't have many functions that XAML editor has. And I just want to open my .txaml files in XAML editor so that I could use all its possibilities

Comment: @ClicheCoffeeMug I have tried to silve my problem one more time and found out that what I call XAML editor is actually Automatic Editor Selector(XML). And my current situation is that if I open standart .xaml file with Automatic Editor Selector(XML) it opens as standart XAML editor, but if I open my .txaml file the same way with  Automatic Editor Selector(XML) it opens somehow differently as simple XML editor. (by the way, in my .txaml files there is usual xaml code)

Comment: Do you think it is possible to make Automatic Editor Selector(XML) act the same way for .txaml files as it does for .xaml files?

Comment: I haven't had this need before, so I can only make a guess at a solution for you. If you want the normal IntelliSense and other things that come with .xaml files inside VS, I would look into leaving the files as .xaml until compile-time, and then set up some kind of build action or renaming of the .xaml files to the .txaml when you need to build/deploy/run the application. Note that there may be other solutions I am not aware of.

Comment: @ClicheCoffeeMug thank you for the idea, I'll do like that if don't find any other way